# Pulumi on GCP - How to create a Managed Instance Group with Docker Container Instances

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, pulumi, gce-instance-group

I've been attempting to create a managed instance group on GCP which consists of instances that host a custom docker image. However I'm struggling to figure out how to do this with Pulumi.

Reading [Google's GCP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/deploying-containers#managedinstancegroupcontainer) it's possible to deploy instances that host a docker container within a managed instance group via [instance templates](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-templates).

Practically with gcloud this looks like:

```
gcloud compute instance-templates create-with-container TEMPLATE_NAME --container-image DOCKER_IMAGE
```

Reading [Pulumi's instance template documentation](https://www.pulumi.com/registry/packages/gcp/api-docs/compute/instancetemplate/) however, it's not clear how to create an instance template which would do the same thing as the command above.

Is it possible in Pulumi to create a managed instance group where the instances host a custom docker image, or will I have to do something like create an instance template manually, and refer to that within my Pulumi script?

Comment: I do not work with Pulimi, but I do with Terraform and the REST APIs. I would first figure out how to create an instance specifying the COS image **cos-stable**. Then figure out how to specify the cloud-init configuration file which declares the container to run. Once you have the basics figured out, create an instance template. The CLI command in your question is actually very complicated and performs many steps in a single command. This link might help: https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/how-to/create-configure-instance#using_cloud-init_with_the_cloud_config_format

Comment: As a suggestion, your question is too broad and requires a large amount of code to reproduce the CLI command. Create smaller questions that do not require a week of work to write.

Comment: Thanks for your insight @JohnHanley. 

I disagree that the question is too broad - I'd say it's actually quite specific and hopefully clear what I'm after. 

It is insightful though if the automated solution requires a tonne of work. My hope was that Pulumi being a wrapper around Terraform would make the job easier, but perhaps that's not the case. 

Ideally someone in the community has solved this and has a solution already and would be open to sharing how they did that. I'm not expecting anyone to figure this out from scratch just to answer my question.

Comment: @JohnHanley for starters, I've included a relevant gcloud snippet that achieves what I'm after. You've assumed that the solution is complicated and requires a "week of work" to write. If the question is not clear then I'm happy to clarify. However if your complaint is that the solution is a lot of code, then I don't think that goes against the stack overflow ethos, let the answer be "it's a lot of code" and hopefully provide at least some high level steps in which to solve the issue. I'd be happy to fill in the details at a later stage in my own answer.

Comment: @JohnHanley - my question is essentially about reproducing the gcloud command in Pulumi. There is no example Pulumi code because it's not clear how to do exactly that. I have read the guidelines and I'm not sure how or why you feel I'm not following them? I've provided enough information to explain what it is I'm trying to achieve, it's a problem I'm sure many others will come across, and yet here you are trying to close the issue. In my view that's doing a disservice to the community as it's something that will undoubtedly come up many times in the future for others.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hybrid approach that utilises both [gcloud](https://cloud.google.com/sdk) and [Pulumi](https://www.pulumi.com/).

**At a high level:**

1. Create a [docker container](https://www.docker.com/) and upload to the [Google Container Registry](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry)
2. Create an [instance template](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-templates) using [gcloud](https://cloud.google.com/sdk)
3. Create a managed instance group, referencing the instance template from within the Pulumi script

---

**#1 Creating the Docker Container**

Use [CloudBuild](https://cloud.google.com/build) to detect changes within a Git repo, create a docker container, and upload it to the Google Container Registry.

Within my repo I have a [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) file with instructions on how to build the container that will be used for my instance. I use [Supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) to start and monitor my application.

Here's how it looks:

```sh
# my-app-repo/Dockerfile

FROM ubuntu:22.04

RUN apt update
RUN apt -y install software-properties-common

RUN apt install -y supervisor
COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisord.conf
RUN chmod 0700 /etc/supervisord.conf

COPY ./my-app /home/my-app
RUN chmod u+x /home/my-app

EXPOSE 443/tcp # HTTPS
EXPOSE 9001/tcp # supervisord support

CMD ["supervisord", "-c", "/etc/supervisord.conf"]
```

The second part of this is to build the docker container and upload to the Google Container Registry. I do this via CloudBuild. Here's the corresponding Pulumi code (building a Golang app):

*Note: make sure you've connected the repo via the [CloudBuild section](https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/triggers) of the GCP website first*

```
const myImageName = pulumi.interpolate`gcr.io/${project}/my-image-name`
const buildTrigger = new gcp.cloudbuild.Trigger("my-app-build-trigger", {
  name: "my-app",
  description: "Builds My App image",
  build: {
    steps: [
      {
        name: "golang",
        id: "build-server",
        entrypoint: "bash",
        timeout: "300s",
        args: ["-c", "go build"],
      },
      {
        name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker",
        id: "build-docker-image",
        args: [
          "build",
          "-t", pulumi.interpolate`${myImageName}:$BRANCH_NAME-$REVISION_ID`,
          "-t", pulumi.interpolate`${myImageName}:latest`,
          '.',
        ],
      },
    ],
    images: [myImageName]
  },
  github: {
    name: "my-app-repo",
    owner: "MyGithubUsername",
    push: {
      branch: "^main$"
    }
  },
});
```

**#2 Creating an Instance Template**

As I haven't been able to figure out how to easily create an instance template via Pulumi, I decided to use the Google SDK via the `gcloud` commandline tool.

```sh
gcloud compute instance-templates create-with-container my-template-name-01 \
--region us-central1 \
--container-image=gcr.io/my-project/my-image-name:main-e286d94217719c3be79aac1cbd39c0a629b84de3 \
--machine-type=e2-micro \
--network=my-network-name-59c9c08 \
--tags=my-tag-name \
--service-account=my-service-account@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

The values for above (container, network name etc) I got simply by browsing my project on the [GCP website](https://console.cloud.google.com/).

**#3 Creating the Managed Instance Group**

Having created an instance template you can now reference that template within your Pulumi script

```
const myHealthCheck = new gcp.compute.HealthCheck("my-app-health-check", {
  checkIntervalSec: 5,
  timeoutSec: 5,
  healthyThreshold: 2,
  unhealthyThreshold: 5,
  httpHealthCheck: {
    requestPath: "/health-check",
    port: 80,
  },
});

const instanceGroupManager = new gcp.compute.InstanceGroupManager("my-app-instance-group", {
  baseInstanceName: "my-app-name-prefix",
  zone: hostZone,
  targetSize: 2,
  versions: [
    {
      name: "my-app",
      instanceTemplate: "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/my-project/global/instanceTemplates/my-template-name-01",
    },
  ],
  autoHealingPolicies: {
    healthCheck: myHealthCheck.id,
    initialDelaySec: 300,
  },
});
```

For completeness, I've also included another part of my Pulumi script which creates a backend service and connects it to the instance group created above via the [InstanceGroupManager](https://www.pulumi.com/registry/packages/gcp/api-docs/compute/instancegroupmanager/) call. Note that the Load Balancer in this example is using TCP instead of HTTPS (My App is handling SSL connections and thus uses a [TCP Network Load Balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/network)).

```
const backendService = new gcp.compute.RegionBackendService("my-app-backend-service", {
  region: hostRegion,
  enableCdn: false,
  protocol: "TCP",
  backends: [{
    group: instanceGroupManager.instanceGroup,
  }],
  healthChecks: defaultHttpHealthCheck.id,
  loadBalancingScheme: "EXTERNAL",
});

const myForwardingRule = new gcp.compute.ForwardingRule("my-app-forwarding-rule", {
  description: "HTTPS forwarding rule",
  region: hostRegion,
  ipAddress: myIPAddress.address,
  backendService: backendService.id,
  portRange: "443",
});
```

---

*Note: Ideally step #2 would be done with Pulumi as well however I haven't worked that part out just yet.*